# Express Form Redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I made a homepage for my Express.js website that has 2 buttons for logging in and signing up. However, when I click on the button, why am I not being redirected to the login and sign up pages? Below are my view for the home page and the routes for the homepage.

View for home page:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Welcome to Resume to Job!
  style(type='text/css').
    h1 {
      margin-left: 250px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  body
    form(action= '/signup', name='signup' method='GET')
      input(type='submit', value='Sign Up')
    form(action='/login', name='login', method='GET')
      input(type='submit', value='Log In')
    style(type='text/css').
      form {
        margin-left: 610px;
        color: DodgerBlue;
        font-size: 40px;
        padding-top:100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
      }
```

Router for homepage:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var sign_up_controller = require('../controllers/signUpController');
var login_controller = require('../controllers/logInController');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
  next();
}, function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/signup');
});
router.get('/signup', sign_up_controller.sign_up);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please note 2 different scenarios: 1. The user clicks something, so the browser makes a request and server gives response(usually with HTML). 2. The server decides that it wont serve the HTML for this URL, so the server set response header - without any HTML, telling the user to go to different URL. Hope this clarify things for you.

Comment: Also worth mentioning - 1. If you have printed any HTML to the user from the server, you cant go back to set response header. 2. The name of the redirect response header is `Location`.